# Bind Tmux prefix to Space-w

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I'm trying to bind my Tmux Prefix to <kbd>Space</kbd> - <kbd>w</kbd> but can't seem to unbind the `C` prefix.

That's where i'm stuck

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind Space send-prefix
```

How can I bind the prefix to <kbd>Space</kbd> - <kbd>w</kbd>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind multiple character combinations to perform an action in tmux (at least not up to current version `2.0`).

That means binding `space` + `w` won't work.

If the above holds true, you might wonder how come `ctrl` key combinations work, for example `Ctrl-b`? The reason for this is that `Ctrl-b` is a **single** character, even though 2 keyboard keys are required to generate it.

Here's a good [ascii table](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html) that shows which `control` keys are mapped to which ascii values. Example: `Ctrl-b` has value `2`.